# Hide Columns in responsive table using media queries

Tags: css, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

hey i am stuck to display my django app on mobile.
in template, table has 4-5 column (display well in desktop)

while on mobile, i want to display only one column and rest of columns data should be display when click on that only one column (in the form of collaps)

so to hidden all column i tried this in my css

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px){
    //for header     and    for td to hide 
    tr th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(2),
    tr th:nth-child(3), tr td:nth-child(3),
    tr th:nth-child(4), tr td:nth-child(4),
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

it display only one column, but how to get its related data while clicking on rows
(in form of collaps)?

thanx in adavance

Comment: please show me the way to do that ... ?

Comment: have you tried just adding "hidden-sm" or "hidden-xs" to the th/td tags that you want to disappear?

Comment: oh, sorry...I understand what you're saying now...you need to make some JavaScript that will show that data in some kind of popup on click for a phone...or some other similar method.

Comment: try footables: http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/ - js plugin that collapses table cells as needed.

Comment: @KevinNelson Right ....
collapses is best look and feel for mobile than popups ..

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has answered this, I'll go ahead and give you my take on it.

Anyway, to turn it into a collapse/accordion style instead of a popover or something similar, you'll probably want to use DIVs instead of TABLEs. Then, you'll have to do redundant data so that the data you are going to make invisible is also inside the collapse section. Then, you need to write some script that only catches the accordion click when the display is the smaller screen-size so that there is no accordion when all the data is visible.  You'll also need a column that will be visible only to small screens to indicate that it's an accordion to the user so they know they can click it...in any case, lots of work ahead of you, I would imagine, and more than I can put in an answer because this kind of work all depends on preference and requirements that I don't have.

OR

Personally, the method I've taken with similar issues is to create some CSS for `.responsive-table` that forces .col-* inside to have `nowrap` a specific height, and hidden overflow (and `text-overflow:ellipsis` if you like).  This allows me to force my columns to take up the col-*-x width I want based on screen size and not introduce weird wrapping when the screen shrinks too much.  Beyond that, I then just write responsive code the good-old Bootstrap way and make it so that my single `.row` will be two rows on smaller screens, e.g.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6'></div>
    <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6'></div>
    <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6'></div>
    <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6'></div>
</div>
```

This will make that one row take up two rows space on a smaller screen.  I do the exact same HTML for the "table header" so that the header matches the wrapping scheme...which is also why the nowrap is required because without nowrap, the individual rows may stop matching the header. However, you still run into readability problems where all the rows run together.  So, to solve this, I do a media query that will separate the rows with some visual space on smaller screens: e.g.

```
@media(max-width 768px) {
    .responsive-table .row { margin-bottom:3px }
}
```

This visual spacing is more clear if there is a slight background-color on the rows or borders, or some other form of visual indicators for visual separation.